# Angular and Redux: is it right to dispatch two actions (one sync, one async) triggered by one user interaction?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I have a general question regarding to flow of actions in Redux application implemented in Angular 4 and ngrx-store.

(based on an excellent post: http://onehungrymind.com/build-better-angular-2-application-redux-ngrx/)

There is an Angular component - container component (it contains behavior). It has a reference to a service which uses to load data.

Component loads data. Once the data arrives there is an action dispatched to the store (in service) `PAGE_LOADED`.
The component is subscribed to store for items:

Component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'list',
    templateUrl: './list.component.html'
})
export class ListComponent {

    private list$: Observable;
    private items: Item[];

    constructor(private client: RestClient, private store: Store) {
        this.list$ = this.store.select('items');
        this.list$.subscribe(
            list => this.items = (list ? list : []));

        this.client.loadItems(new PageInfo(0, 10)); // load first page on init, 10 items
    }

    onPageChanged(pageInfo: PageInfo) {
        this.store.dispatch({action: 'PAGE_CHANGED', payload: pageInfo});
        this.client.loadList(pageInfo); // load next page
    }

}
```

And the service:

```
@Injectable()
export class RestClient {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private store: Store) {}

    public loadItems(pageInfo: PageInfo): void {
        this.http.get('items', {params: {page: pageInfo.page, itemsPerPage: page.size}})
            .map(payload => ({
                type: 'PAGE_LOADED',
                payload: payload
            }))
            .subscribe(action => this.store.dispatch(action));
    }
}
```

The component has a child component - pagination presentational component (does not contain behavior, or reference to store - its Bootstrap implementation), that emmits page changes using Angular `@Output()` and `EventEmitter`. The parent component implements `onPageChanged(pageInfo)` function that receives the page changes events emitted by the child component.

And now the question, or confusion:
On page change new value has to be dispatched to store and new data has to be loaded.

What should be done in `onPageChange` function:

```
onPageChanged(pageInfo: PageInfo) {
        this.store.dispatch({action: 'PAGE_CHANGED', payload: pageInfo});
        this.client.loadList(pageInfo); // load next page
    }
```

1. paging has been changed so an action is dispatched to store: `PAGE_CHANGED`
   with `PageInfo` - current page a and page size
2. next page has to be loaded: so next step is to call the `RestClient` service for next page: `this.client.loadList(pageInfo);`
   This call in turn (asynchronously) dispatches a new action that next page has been loaded.

In sum the page change in UI emitts two actions:
- `PAGE_CHANGE`
- `PAGE_LOADED`

Is it correct that there are two actions dispatched on `onPageChange` action?
Should these two be chained in sense that:

```
store.select('pageInfo')
    .subscribe(pageInfo => this.client.loadList(pageInfo));
```

Or is there other and better solution to this issue?

Comment: No, Don't ever do this.  A store result should never trigger an action, this breaks the unidirectional flow of information.  This creates potential for near impossible to find bugs and even could cause a very weird infinite loop in your application.  If you watch the initial Facebook presentation on Redux, they talk about how things like this is exactly what Redux was meant to solve.  You're creating a side effect when you do this which is exactly what you're not supposed to do.

You should use ngrx's effects service for this.

Comment: First, thanks for reading such a long question :)

I think this is very common scenario: a user action causes an action to be dispatched (store updated) and new data has to be loaded which in turn causes update to store.

Is there a way to solve this without ngrx effects, a general Redux way?

Comment: Why you don't want to use [**@ngrx/effects**](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/effects/README.md)? It's made for such a common case like yours.

Comment: I am probably going to use it once I understand *how to* to do it correctly :)

I was just wandering what is behind ngrx effect, if there is a similar approach in "clean" Redux architecture.

And if there is a solution using ngrx effects please post it as an answer ;)

Comment: The way to do this without ngrx is to consider them as two wholly separate actions.  The pages gets changed, this causes two distinct state changes, with their own distinct payload that fully describes the individual state change. Action 1 (immediate) causes any instant UI effects needed, such as it shows a loading icon or something.  Then action 2 (async) gets dispatched after you've retrieved the data needed to describe the state change which updates the data and shuts off the loading icon.  ngrx/effects helps make the bridge between these actions clearer and the event order more intuitive.

Comment: @bryan60 You have described what I have now in `onPageChanged()` 

1. *immediate* - `this.store.dispatch({action: 'PAGE_CHANGED', payload: pageInfo});`
2. *async*: `this.client.loadList(pageInfo);`

So I consider it as a `correct` way to do it with a note that it is better to use ngrx effects to achieve same behavior.

Comment: yes, i agree. It is a common case and the disconnect between 2 clearly related events is a little unintuitive.  and this is why effects was born.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is as bryan60 suggested, using ngrx effects library:

```
onPageChanged(pageInfo: PageInfo) {
    this.store.dispatch({action: 'PAGE_CHANGED', payload: pageInfo});
}
```

`onPageChange` dispatches action `PAGE_CHANGED` which updates store with new paging information.

There is a side effect registered, that on `PAGE_CHANGE` loads a new page and asynchronously triggers `LOAD_SUCCESS` or `LOAD_ERROR`:

```
@Effect() changePage$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(applications.CHANGE_PAGE)
    .switchMap(action => this.client.loadItems(page, itemsPerPage)
        .map(payload => (new applications.LoadSuccessAction(payload)))
        // If request fails, dispatch failed action
        .catch(error => Observable.of(new applications.LoadErrorAction(error)))
    );
```

Rest client does not dispatch actions any more:

```
@Injectable()
export class RestClient {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private store: Store) {}

    public loadItems(pageInfo: PageInfo): Observable {
        return this.http.get('items', {params: {page: pageInfo.page, itemsPerPage: page.size}});
    }
}
```

Register effects in `app.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
       ...        
       EffectsModule.run(ApplicationEffects),
       ...
```